# Decreasing font size of android studio in presentation

Tags: android, android-studio

I know the way to change font size in android studio, but Is it possible to change the font size of android studio in presentation mode.

Comment: what do you mean by presentation mode ?

Comment: Presentation mode option comes when you click 

view->Enter Presentation Mode

Comment: Check : https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/viewing-modes.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana Your link doesn't have anything to configure font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intellij-idea-viewing-modes.html

You can define font size for the presentation mode in the Appearance page of the Settings dialog.

I can see the option at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

- go to Settings-Editor and check "Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl +
  Mouse Wheel" (it's for Windows).
- switch to Presentation Mode.
- use Ctrl+Mouse Wheel to change font size (increase/decrease);

P.S.: but, unfortunately, you'll need to zoom each editor tab.